# Finding the differences only between 2 strings in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, attributes, xquery

I must compare 2 xml strings(varchar(max) in sql) like these ones:

```
'<table_name id="2" name="Bob"  job="student"/>'

'<table_name id="2" name="john" job="teacher"/>'
```

And the result must be the differences only, which means, ill get 2 strings, the first one will me the original values, and the second one will be the new values. However if there are no differences then there will be an empty string, in this case for example:

output 1: 'name="Bob", job="student"'

output 2: 'name="john", job="teacher"'

As you see, we didn't get the id string attached because there wasn't any change, so naturally, no changes means no string to return.

Comment: Do you want generic method or just for this sample? Specify it before you get answers and you will tell that XML has not schema

Comment: Please be more specific: Are these lines always of the same structure? Is this case sensitive (what about "john" and "John")?

Comment: Bob and john do have the 2nd character as the same though.

Comment: Oh sorry, any type of difference shall be enough to write the whole value. Having 1 character different will make it output the whole thing.

A generic method would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic approach up to 100 Attributs:

```
DECLARE @XML1 XML='<table_name id="2" name="Bob"  job="student"/>';
DECLARE @XML2 XML='<table_name id="2" name="john" job="teacher"/>';

WITH CountAttributs AS
(
    SELECT LEN(CAST(@XML1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)))-LEN(REPLACE(CAST(@XML1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'=','')) AS X
)
, E1(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)) --10 ^ 1
, E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b) -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
, CteTally AS
(
    SELECT TOP((SELECT X FROM CountAttributs)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS Nmbr
    FROM E2
)
,AttributNames AS
(
    SELECT Nmbr,@XML1.value('local-name((*/@*[sql:column("Nmbr")])[1])', 'varchar(max)') AS AttributName
    FROM CteTally
)
SELECT
(
    SELECT '' + CASE WHEN @XML1.value('(*/@*[fn:local-name()=sql:column("AttributName")])[1]','varchar(max)')
                          <> @XML2.value('(*/@*[fn:local-name()=sql:column("AttributName")])[1]','varchar(max)') 
                     THEN AttributName + ': ' + @XML2.value('(*/@*[fn:local-name()=sql:column("AttributName")])[1]','varchar(max)') + ', ' ELSE '' END 
    FROM AttributNames
    FOR XML PATH('') 
)
```

Result:

```
name: john, job: teacher,
```

Comment: thats really impressive, but could you do also make it it display the original ones that are different to the one compared?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

Paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs:

```
DECLARE @XML1 XML='<table_name id="2" name="Bob"  job="student"/>';
DECLARE @XML2 XML='<table_name id="2" name="john" job="teacher"/>';

WITH AttributValues AS
(
    SELECT @XML1.value('/table_name[1]/@id','varchar(max)') AS id1
          ,@XML1.value('/table_name[1]/@name','varchar(max)') AS name1
          ,@XML1.value('/table_name[1]/@job','varchar(max)') AS job1
          ,@XML2.value('/table_name[1]/@id','varchar(max)') AS id2
          ,@XML2.value('/table_name[1]/@name','varchar(max)') AS name2
          ,@XML2.value('/table_name[1]/@job','varchar(max)') AS job2
)
SELECT 'The differences: '
     + CASE WHEN id1<>id2 THEN 'id: ' + id1 + ' or ' + id2 + ' | ' ELSE '' END  
     + CASE WHEN name1<>name2 THEN 'name: ' + name1 + ' or ' + name2 + ' | ' ELSE '' END  
     + CASE WHEN job1<>job2 THEN 'job: ' + job1 + ' or ' + job2 ELSE '' END  
FROM AttributValues
```

Result

```
The differences: name: Bob or john | name: student or teacher
```

Comment: Great solution but with big assumption about data structure in XML. OP does not specify that  every row has that schema

Comment: Well, it is at least an example which the OP could use to find similar solutions for other XMLs. I do not really assume, that the OP is looking for a totally generic solution...

Comment: Sorry I didnt especify, it must be generic for any 2 xmls to be compared

Comment: @lad2025, what shall I say... big assumptions... wrong assumptions... One shouldn't be to eager ;-)

Comment: @Shnugo I would say: That's life :)

Comment: @BobXplosion. in this case (generic solution) I must admit, that "Adam V" is right with question: Why SQL? This is - if there is literally everything allowed - much to complicated... You could have nested elements, different counts of nested elements, hierarchically deep structures, identical values with differing namespaces... Please give more details!

Comment: There is not gonna be any nested values, its gonna be always a simple tag with <tagname name_of_value="value">, just ignore the tag name and everything else other than the name_of_value and its value. any of the strings might have any number of values but always in the same format, never will there be nested or repeated namespaces