# Get the Missing and Excess tags from a XML field

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table, `Customer(Id int,Name nvarchar(100),Detail xml)`

```
Sample Data:
1,'Abc','<ROOT> <TAG1>False</TAG1>  <TAG3>value</TAG3> <TAG14>value</TAG14> </ROOT>'
2,'Pqr','<ROOT> <TAG2>False</TAG2>  <TAG8>value</TAG8> <TAG11>value</TAG11> </ROOT>'
```

Also I have `XML variable , @v_xml = '<ROOT> <TAG1>value</TAG1>  <TAG2>value</TAG2> <TAG8>False</TAG8> <TAG14>False</TAG14> </ROOT>'`.

Now I want get the Missing Tags and Excess Tags (in XML format) of each `Customer` comparing to the XML variable `@v_xml` (No need to consider the value, what ever it may be)

```
Expected Result:
Id Name  Missing                                                Excess
1,'Abc','<ROOT><TAG2>value</TAG2> <TAG8>value</TAG8> </ROOT>','<ROOT><TAG3>value</TAG3> </ROOT>'
2,'Pqr','<ROOT><TAG1>value</TAG1> <TAG14>False</TAG14> </ROOT>','<ROOT><TAG11>value</TAG11> </ROOT>'
```

There is no nested nodes/level in the XML. Only direct child elements under `ROOT` tag. But the number of child tags will vary. I am looking for a simple and common logic to resolve this (with or without SQL query).

Comment: You find something (about attributes) similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33618799/5089204)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main idea parse tag name (`local-name(.)`) and concat diffs into xml

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    X XML
)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    (1, 'Abc', N'<ROOT><TAG1>False</TAG1><TAG3>value</TAG3><TAG14>value</TAG14></ROOT>'),
    (2, 'Pqr', N'<ROOT><TAG2>False</TAG2><TAG8>value</TAG8><TAG11>value</TAG11></ROOT>')

DECLARE @x XML = N'<ROOT><TAG1>value</TAG1><TAG2>value</TAG2><TAG8>False</TAG8><TAG14>False</TAG14></ROOT>'

SELECT t.Id, t.Name, t2.val.query('Missing/*'), t2.val.query('Excess/*')
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  
        Missing = Missing.query,
        Excess = Excess.query
    FROM (
        SELECT
            query = t.c.query('.'),
            tag = t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'SYSNAME')
        FROM x.nodes('*/*') t(c)
    ) Excess
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT
            query = t.c.query('.'),
            tag = t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'SYSNAME')
        FROM @x.nodes('*/*') t(c)
    ) Missing ON Missing.tag = Excess.tag
    WHERE Missing.tag IS NULL
        OR Excess.tag IS NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) t2 (val)
```

Output -

```
----------- ---------- ------------------------- ------------------------------------------
1           Abc        <TAG3>value</TAG3>        <TAG2>value</TAG2><TAG8>False</TAG8>
2           Pqr        <TAG11>value</TAG11>      <TAG1>value</TAG1><TAG14>False</TAG14>
```

Comment: Great, you were faster!